# What is the error in this query

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054

- Database: tennis
- table: matches
- columns: matchno(pk), won, lost ...etc

Problem:
Get the match number and the sets won and lost in each match where num of sets won is >= num of sets lost multiplied by 2.

Wrong query:

```
use tennis;
select matchno, lost * 2 AS spl
from matches 
where won >= spl
```

What is wrong in this query? How can it be modified to get the right output?

Correct query:

```
select matchno, won, lost
from matches
where won >= lost * 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT matchno, lost * 2 AS spl
FROM matches
WHERE won >= (lost * 2)
```